# Accessing a Hash in a REST POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

I have a hash in Ruby:

```
params={"username"=>"test"}
```

I want to add another associative array like:

```
params["user"]={"name"=>"test2"}
```

so `params` should become

```
params={"username"=>"test","user"=>{"name"=>"test2"}}
```

but when I post this params to a url, I get:

```
params[:user][:name] # => nil
```

when I dump the user data:

```
 params[:user] # => ['name','test2']
```

what I want is

```
 params[:user] # => output {'name'=>'test2'}
```

what am I doing wrong? thanks for help.

Comment: it's important to use the usual terminology for each language: in Ruby it's Hash.

Comment: I've added the Ruby on Rails tag to your question under the assumption that this is the web framework you are using. (Ruby is a programming language; Rails is a web framework that uses Ruby.) If this is not correct, please update your question with the web framework you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just using wrong key, you think that `:user` and `"user"` are the same, which is not.

```
params["user"]["name"] #=> "test2"
params["user"]         #=> {"name"=>"test2"}
```

**UPDATE** from Naveed:

:user is an instance of Symbol class while "user" is instance of String

Comment: In ruby a hash can have any object as a key, so the object "user" is different from the object :user.

Comment: :user is an instance of Symbol class while "user" is instance of String. they are not same at all.if you in rials you can use 'HashWithIndifferentAccess' now values from this hash can be accessed via String and Symbol.

Answer (score 2):

You have created a hash with keys of type string and trying to access with symbol keys. This works only with class [HashWithIndifferentAccess](http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html).

If you want to achieve the same convert your `hash` to `HashWithIndifferentAccess` by using `with_indifferent_access` method,

```
> params = {"username"=>"test", "user"=>{"name"=>"test2"}}
=> {"username"=>"test", "user"=>{"name"=>"test2"}}
> params[:user][:name]
=> nil
>params = params.with_indifferent_access
> params[:user][:name]
=> "test2"
```

Update: `request params` is an instance of `HashWithIndifferentAccess`

Comment: I add 'params.with_indifferent_access' , it outputs the same when I asscess params[:user], outputs ['name','test2'].

Comment: wait, it says undifined method 'with_indifferent_access'?

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
params["user"]
```

Comment: does not work, exceptions: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!

Comment: That could be the full stop at the end, I've removed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
params={"username"=>"test"}# params is not array nor associative array its a hash
```

you can add key value pair in hash by

```
params["key"]="value"
```

key and value both can be object of any class,be sure you use same object as key to access value or take a look at 
 [HashWithIndifferentAccess](http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html)

now

```
 params["user"]={"name"=>"blah"}
 params["user"]   # => {"name"=>"blah"}
 params["user"]["name"] # => "blah"
```